# Friend definition doesn't work with gcc4.9

Tags: c++, gcc, friend, dynamic-library

I need to create a dynamic library:

**mylib.h**

```
class FriendClass;

namespace my_namespace
{

class MyLib
{
    friend class FriendClass;

public:
    MyLib();

    /* public functions */

private:
    void function_for_friend_class();
};

} // namespace my_namespace
```

And use it here

**friend_function.h**

```
class FriendClass
{
public:
    void some_function()
    {
        MyLib* my_lib = get_my_lib_somehow();
        my_lib->function_for_friend_class();
    }
};
```

With gcc3.4 it compiles, but gcc4.9 complains that function_for_friend_class is private. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try either  `friend class ::FriendClass;`. or `friend FriendClass;`

Comment: But isn't it looking into global namespace, when it'll not find in current one?

Comment: `friend class xxx` declares a new class if possible, `friend xxx` looks for an existing class.

Comment: gcc34 - "a class-key must be used when declaring a friend", only `class ::FriendClass` works in both versions.

Comment: 3.4 is old and may not be fully conforming.

Comment: @n.m. It's weird to me. For [friend elaborated-class-name;](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend), why unqualified name lookup doesn't find the name in global scope for [Elaborated type specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)?

Comment: @songyuanyao hmm it looks like I was wrong, `friend class xxx declares a new class if possible` is incorrect, the program seems OK and gcc 4.9 is wrong.

Comment: @n.m. if that's the case, add clang 3.8 to the list. `friend FriendClass;` properly resolves; `friend class FriendClass;` does not, when setup as the OP describes. See it [fail to compile here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3900ca1ad9a2fddc), and [succeed here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c43db5007f50655c)

Comment: @n.m. But Clang failed too...Clang and GCC are both wrong? Maybe we still missed something..

Comment: @songyuanyao No wait, either I misunderstand something in the standard or gcc, clang and icc are all wrong, which would be weird. Microsoft compilers accept this.

Comment: @n.m. Maybe VS is correct? Which is the most weird to me..

Comment: @songyuanyao OK I think I found it: *If the name in a friend declaration is neither qualified nor a template-id and the declaration is a function or an elaborated-type-specifier, the lookup to determine whether the entity has
been previously declared shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace" (7.3.1.2/3). So the lookup should not find the global FriendClass, and thus the friend declaration introduces a new FriendClass in MyLib namespace. I was right and the usual suspect is wrong after all.

Comment: @n.m. Awesome! This is the answer. (You might put it as the answer, with the workaround together.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `friend class ::FriendClass;`
By doing this, you tell the compiler to look in the global namespace of the definition of `class FriendClass`, not in the current namespace.

Also use:

```
my_namespace::MyLib* my_lib = get_my_lib_somehow();
```

Comment: Because by writing "friend class FriendClass;" you tell the compiler to look in the current namespace only, non in the global one.

Comment: [Unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Namespace_scope) should find the name if you don't specify the scope explicitly. The problem is why it doesn't work here.